# Bootstrap 4 Progress bar alignment

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a rating indicator using bootstrap 4 progress bar. Following is what I'm trying to achieve. However bootstrap progress bar using flex hence I can't align the text in the left and right.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8x2stLup/)

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <div class="review__rating__stats">

            <span class="review__rating__progress">
                <span class="review__rating__level">5 Star</span>
                <span class="progress">
                    <span class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></span>
                </span>
                <span class="review__rating__count">68</span>
            </span>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Couldn't you make five rows, each with three columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to set a width for `.review__rating__count`. The "3" was causing the misalignment because it's a single digit, whereas other counts are double digits, which take up more spaces.

Now you can even set `.review__rating__stats` as flexbox, then use `flex:` to set a default width for `.review__rating__count`.

#### Layout

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="review__rating__stats">
                <div class="review__rating__progress">
                    <strong class="review__rating__level">5 Star</strong>
                    <div class="progress">
                        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 68%" 
                          aria-valuenow="68" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                    </div>
                    <strong class="review__rating__count">68</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="review__rating__progress" />
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Styles

```css
.review__rating__progress {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.review__rating__progress .review__rating__level,
.review__rating__progress .review__rating__count {
    /* 10% is the default width for the level and count labels */
    flex: 1 1 10%;
}

.review__rating__progress .review__rating__level {
    text-align: right;
}

.review__rating__progress .progress {
    margin: 0.25rem 1rem;
    flex-grow: 8;
}
```

#### Result

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/j4y70wfz/36/

Answer (score 1):

Put each progress bar in row like such:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <div class="container review__rating__stats">
      <div class="row review__rating__progress">
        <span class="col-sm-2 review__rating__level">5 Star</span>
        <div class="col-sm-9 align-self-center">
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <span class="col-sm-1 review__rating__count">68</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that the div that contains the progress bar must have the `align-self-center` class otherwise it won't be vertically centered.